# Help me with this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy'-y=x(1+e^{\frac{y}{x}})$$
Please give me a hint on how to solve this. If I'm not mistaken, this is a Bernoulli equation, but I can't seem to solve it using the substitution $z=y^{\frac{1}{1-a}}$. Using variation of constants also didn't help.

Comment: @TIWARI You might mean $y=tx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Try $u=\frac{y}{x}$. Then $y'=u'x+u$.

By the way, this is not Bernoulli.

Answer (score 1):

$y\backprime -\frac { y }{ x } =1+{ e }^{ \frac { y }{ x }  }$   $\frac { y }{ x } =t$ , $\Rightarrow y=xt$ $\Rightarrow y\prime =t\prime x+t$ $\Rightarrow y\prime =t\prime x+t$ $ \Rightarrow \int { \frac { dt }{ 1+{ e }^{ t } } =\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  }  } $

Comment: May I suggest to forget completely the odd `\backprime` and `\prime`.